# How to remove "- Swagger UI" from HTML Page title of OpenAPI docs in FastAPI

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, fastapi, openapi

I am trying to customize my OpenAPI (Swagger UI) docs generated by FastAPI, but that string `- Swagger UI` still remains.

```
app = FastAPI(
    title="Test",
    version="0.1.0"
)
```

`HTML` result :

```html
<title>Test - Swagger UI</title>
```

Is there a way to remove this `- Swagger UI` from the title?

Answer (score 1):

The  `- Swagger UI` part is added to the title by FastAPI. To change that, you need to override the `/docs` route, as shown in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#serve-the-static-files) when one wishes to self-host the JS and CSS files for docs. FastAPI provides the [CDN URLs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#download-the-files) for JS and CSS files, thus you could pass those to the parameters below (not necessarily need to download and serve them as static files). Example is given below:

```
from fastapi.openapi.docs import (
    get_swagger_ui_html,
    get_swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_html,
)

app = FastAPI(title ="Test", version="0.1.0", docs_url=None)

@app.get("/docs", include_in_schema=False)
async def custom_swagger_ui_html():
    return get_swagger_ui_html(
        openapi_url=app.openapi_url,
        title=app.title,
        oauth2_redirect_url=app.swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url,
        swagger_js_url="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js",
        swagger_css_url="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui.css")
```